# How to convert following SQL Query into Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have a following SQL Query, which i have converted to Linq, and don't know how can i Convert this query into Lambda Expression.

**SQL**

```sql
 SELECT BP.*
   FROM [ams].[BackgroundPackage] AS BP
        INNER JOIN [ams].[BkgPackageHierarchyMapping] AS BPHM
            ON BP.BPA_ID = BPHM.BPHM_BackgroundPackageID
        INNER JOIN [ams].[BkgOrderPackage] AS BOP
            ON BPHM.BPHM_ID = BOP.BOP_BkgPackageHierarchyMappingID
        INNER JOIN [ams].[BkgOrder] AS BO ON BOP.BOP_BkgOrderID = BO.BOR_ID
  WHERE BO.BOR_MasterOrderID = @OrderID
    AND BO.BOR_IsDeleted = 0
```

**Lambda Version**
 // how to write lambda version of above query

**Linq Version**

```
var packageData =
    (from ep in _dbContext.BackgroundPackages
     join e in _dbContext.BkgPackageHierarchyMappings on ep.BPA_ID equals e.BPHM_BackgroundPackageID
     join t in _dbContext.BkgOrderPackages on e.BPHM_ID equals t.BOP_BkgPackageHierarchyMappingID
     join s in _dbContext.BkgOrders on t.BOP_BkgOrderID equals s.BOR_ID
     where s.BOR_MasterOrderID == orderId
     select new
            {
                Id = ep.BPA_ID,
                Name = ep.BPA_Name,
            });
```

Comment: what's the issue? seems pretty close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the lambda query (concise notation) for your SQL would be:

```
var lambdaQuery = _dbContext.BackgroundPackages
    .Join(_dbContext.BkgPackageHierarchyMappings, ep => ep.BPA_ID, e => e.BPHM_BackgroundPackageID, (ep, e) => ep)
    .Join(_dbContext.BkgOrderPackages, ep => ep.BPHM_ID, t => t.BOP_BkgPackageHierarchyMappingID, (ep, t) => new { ep, t})
    .Join(_dbContext.BkgOrders, ept => ept.t.BOP_BkgOrderID, s => s.BOR_ID, (ept, s) => new { ept.ep, s })
    .Where(eps => eps.s.BOR_MasterOrderID  == orderId && eps.s.BOR_IsDeleted == 0)
    .Select(eps => eps.ep);
```

Comment: @PreetSangha sorry if the answer offended you, i was just trying to answer the question, since Neon-X was looking for a lambda query. (the concise notation, as opposed to the query notation)

Comment: removed -1 now that it's improved.